# Element in list not showing the desired result

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with me which is something like this :

```
ID,Name,Password,Status
arsh@2811,Arsh SHaran,arsh@28112001L?L,True
```

Now I want to check if the status is `True` or not . So I try this :

```
data = pd.read_csv('database.csv')
Status = data['Status'].tolist()
if 'True' in Status :
    return True
else :
    print(Status)
    return False
```

Here the output comes as False even when the `print(Status)` prints `[True]`. How do I go about this ?

Comment: It is parsed as the boolean `True` not string so please try `if True in Status:` or `if any(Status):`.

Comment: Thnx it worked !!